# Прилагательные от слов "мальчик" и "девочка"

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, прилагательные

Как правильно образовать прилагательные от слов **мальчик** и **девочка**?
Правильно ли говорить *мальчиковый* и *девочковый*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От "мальчик" - мальчишеский. И хотя это образование от мальчишка, оно считается нормативным прилагательным для мальчик.
Варианты мальчик**о**вый (и м**а**льчиковый) имеют ограниченное употребление - главным образом в отношении швейных изделий.

Для "девочка" есть только формы девчоночий и девчачий. Непосредственно от "девочка" прилагательное не образуется.

Притяжательные прилагательные - мальчиков и девочкин, но они вопросов  не взывают.

Answer (score 2):

От существительного **девочка** возможно только притяжательное прилагательное - **девочкин** (напр.: *девочкин портфель*).
От существительного **мальчик** - относительное прилагательно **мАльчиковый** (разг. предназначенный для мальчиков (обычно об одежде, обуви), напри.: мальчиковый костюм), и притяжательное - **мальчиков** (как отцов), напр. ситуация в песочнице: "*Это мальчиков мяч, а не твой*".

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё девчоночий и девчачий. У Ожегова:  ДЕВЧО́НОЧИЙ, -ья, -ье и ДЕВЧАЧИЙ, -ья, -ье (разг.). 1. см. девочка. 2. Свойственный девочке, девчонке, такой, как у девочки, девчонки. Девчоночья манера. По-девчоночьи (нареч.) беспечна. Девчачье поведение (несерьёзное).

Comment: Но девчоночий - от девчонка, а девчачий - от девчата. Если строго соблюдать словообразовательные каноны :-))

Comment: язык их не всегда соблюдает

Answer (score 0):

На Грамоте находим:

> Вопрос № 259260
>   Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно поставить ударение в словах мальчиковый/девочковый. Словари не дают однозначного определения.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Предпочтительно ударение: мАльчиковый;  верно: дЕвочкин.

Суммируя с другими ответами, прихожу к выводу, что если мяч, то *мальчиков* или *девочкин*, а если одежда, то *мальчиковая* или *одежда для девочек*.